# Fill Kendo Datasource entity collection on Create

Tags: c#, entity-framework, kendo-ui, entity-framework-6, kendo-datasource

I have an entity called `FileType` in which has a collection called `FileTypeTranslation` that stores all localized properties of this entity. During the create process, I fill this collection with values before to save it.

Entity/Collection are correctly replicating on DB, however if I set the current passed `FileType` context with the new values created, the creation process return the following error:

`A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet1[[Models.Entities.FileTypeTranslation`

Unfortunately I need to replicate to context the changes because I use this same context further to update/delete/etc, and the collection needs to be synced.

**Q: How do I fill an entity collection and properly return it to datasource?**

```
public ActionResult FileType_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, FileType fileType)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var languages = _languageRepository.GetAll();
        var fileTypeTranslations = new List<FileTypeTranslation>();
        foreach (var language in languages)
        {
            fileTypeTranslations.Add(new FileTypeTranslation()
            {
                LanguageId = language.LanguageId,
                TypeName = String.Format("{0}{1}", fileType.TypeName, CultureHelper.GetLanguageSuffix(language.LanguageId))
            });
        }

        var entity = new FileType
        {
            FileTypeId = fileType.FileTypeId,
            AcceptType = fileType.AcceptType,
            FileTypeTranslations = fileTypeTranslations
        };

        //I need to complete my current context for further usages.
        fileType.FileTypeTranslations = entity.FileTypeTranslations;

        _fileTypeRepository.Add(entity);
        _fileTypeRepository.SaveChanges();
        fileType.FileTypeId = entity.FileTypeId;
    }

    return Json(new[] { fileType }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

**Classes**

```
public partial class FileType
{
    [Key]
    public long FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AcceptType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileTypeTranslation> FileTypeTranslations { get; set; }

    public FileType()
    {
        this.FileTypeTranslations = new HashSet<FileTypeTranslation>();
    }
}

public class FileTypeTranslation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long FileTypeId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long LanguageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual FileType FileType { get; set; }
}
```

**DBContext**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FileTypeTranslation>()
            .HasRequired<FileType>(c => c.FileType)
            .WithMany(c => c.FileTypeTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.FileTypeId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Can we see your business object declarations and your DBContext. It is likely you need to set up some relations using ModelBuilder

Comment: @kirsteng sure! Please, have a look the updated post. I guess it will help you.

Comment: It seems odd to have FileTypeId as the primary key to your FileTypeTranslation class.

Also the lambda expression looks strange to me. I would have .HasRequired(x=>c.FileType) instead of .HasRequired<FileType)(c=>FileTypeId)

Comment: @kirsteng indeed `FileTypeTranslation` class has a composite key (FileTypeId and LanguageId), it's correctly. I just edit and fix key order code and you are right the model builder was set wrongly because a paste a commented code, sorry about that. The rest is ok... I still facing the same issue to set my collection as demonstrated.

Comment: I think you need to add the [key] attribute to FileTypeId in the FileType class

Comment: @kirsteng it's a partial class. All the DataAnnotations are on metadadata. The key is set here. Classes are working as expected. Are you sure you understood my issue?

Comment: In my experience circular references are to do with the data structure or how it is communicated to EF via modelbuilder and attributes.

Comment: @kirsteng have you worked with Kendo Datasource? My entities are working fine. I can set the collection and save the entity but I guess the datasource not accept the entity back with a filled collection on server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157248/discussion-between-rubens-mussi-cury-and-kirsten-g).